# Mac app to create a folder structure?

Tags: macos

I always use the same folder structure in my projects (includes/ classes/ style.css index.php)

Is there a mac app which i can create this structure automatically ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an AppleScript, create them in the script or call a shell script for folder creation.

See [this discussion](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-70505.html) for example